# SSH server refuses multiple connections from same client

Tags: linux, ssh, docker, x11, alpine

I have a simple openssh server running in a Alpine Linux 3.15 Docker container, and a client, also running on another Docker container (same version of Alpine of the server) that runs a X server with dwm

The client is able to open a graphical application (`st`) through X11 forwarding from the server to the client display, the problem is that i can only open a single instance of `st` before receiving the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.2 port 22: Connection refused
```

server-side log:

```
Starting session: command on pts/1 for client from 172.17.0.3 port 34060 id 0
debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
debug1: X11 connection requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [X11 connection from 172.17.0.2 port 35028]
debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
debug1: session_by_pid: pid 9
debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 9
debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
debug1: session_by_tty: session 0 tty /dev/pts/1
debug1: session_pty_cleanup2: session 0 release /dev/pts/1
debug1: channel 3: free: X11 connection from 172.17.0.2 port 35028, nchannels 4
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 0 child 0
debug1: session_close_x11: detach x11 channel 1
debug1: session_close_x11: detach x11 channel 2
Close session: user client from 172.17.0.3 port 34060 id 0
debug1: channel 0: free: server-session, nchannels 3
debug1: channel 1: free: X11 inet listener, nchannels 2
debug1: channel 2: free: X11 inet listener, nchannels 1
Received disconnect from 172.17.0.3 port 34060:11: disconnected by user
Disconnected from user client 172.17.0.3 port 34060
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: do_cleanup
```

client-side log:

```
Running /usr/bin/xauth remove ssh:10.0
/usr/bin/xauth add ssh:10.0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 49907415ff518044198f6f0075f270fe
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from 172.17.0.2 35028
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to 172.17.0.2 [172.17.0.2] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 172.17.0.2 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.2 port 22: Connection refused
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 1: free: x11, nchannels 2
X connection to ssh:10.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 172.17.0.2 closed.
Transferred: sent 91292, received 92728 bytes, in 3.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 29350.8, received 29812.5
debug1: Exit status 1
(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

deallocvt: can't open console
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "-d" option of the`sshd` command is used for debugging. It has this effect:

> Debug mode. The server sends verbose debug output to standard error, and does not put itself in the background. **The server also will not fork(2) and will only process one connection.** This option is only intended for debugging for the server. Multiple -d options increase the debugging level. Maximum is 3.

Thanks to [Kenster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/41659/kenster) for his [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/693341/274181) on Unix & Linux StackExchange